# Drawing a Partitioned a Set Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

This question has me stumped, and I was wondering if anyone has an elegant solution. How can I draw a partitioned set in LaTex using Tikz so that it looks similar to the following diagram? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548342/47927) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/594966/47927) can get you started …

Comment: Do the yellow curves have to be of different line width? Other than that, all I see is an ellipse with some possibly clipped curves. Do the partitions need to follow any rules?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to learn how to clip and make curves. I am ok with lines I was having a difficult time finding literature for partitioning an object. No rules, just partitioning at random.

Answer (score 1):

a not perfect proposal that can be a start

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            \node [draw,ellipse,minimum width=8cm,minimum height=3cm,thick](ell) at (0,0){};
            
            \draw[orange,ultra thick] (ell.150) to [out=-90, in=70]  coordinate[pos=0.35](p1)(ell.220);
            \draw[orange,ultra thick] (p1) to [out=10, in=100] (ell.310) coordinate[pos=0.55](p2);
            \draw[orange,ultra thick] (p2) to [out=45, in=-90] (ell.60) coordinate[pos=0.6](p3);
            
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you add `outer sep=-.5\pgflinewidth` the border anchors `.150`, `.310` and `.60` lie on the inside of the ellipse's path. Move the `coordinate` definition of `p2` before the target coordinate as in your first `\draw` command. and the third line would start neatly at the second line. (Same for `p3` but you don't use that anyway.)